# which apps comes free with yosemite macbook pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mac-appstore

i want to know which apps comes free when buy apple macbook pro os x yosemite new. I want to see 1st look of app. Can anyone tell me. I m afraid if i missed anyone while reinstalling again!cos i feel i had 2 pages when i 1st time start my laptop.
Is final cut pro and logic pro comes free when anyone buy new macbook? I feel i had this, just a doubt :(.
or if i give them back to fix will they install?

Answer (score 1):

See [this list](http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/built-in-apps-retina/) on apple.com for the applications which are included with a new MacBook Pro. If you are missing additional applications after a reinstall, you can either re-download them from the Mac App Store or from the website of the vendor (in case the software wasn't purchased through the App Store).

Comment: Thank u so much for that fastest answer. I REALLY APPRECIATE :)

Comment: SO FINAL CUT AND LOGIC PRO ARE NOT PREINSTALLED IN IT?!

Comment: Usually not, but check the Purchased section in the App Store if you think you've bought them already.

Comment: no,i didn't bought it,i wanted to know if its already installed in mac.i m not sure.thanks anyway :)